# Source application close when click back on destination application - android

Tags: android

I am opening My App(Destination-Custom file extension) from Telegram application(Source). And it is Working fine,opening file in My app(Using mimeType,pathPattern).

But when click on BACK button My App has closed(fine).. Telegram Application also closed(Should not happen).

Is there any way Destination app(Telegram) should run on background even you clicked on back on Source App(My app).

Simply issue is: Telegram->My App->clicked BACK===>Total apps are closed(Telegram+My app)

Requirement:Telegram->My App->clicked BACK===>Telegram

I am using fragments.

Can I get any help on this!

Code:
there are two tabs(so two fragments,each for one tab)

In one of the fragment

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   Intent intent =getActivity().getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (intent != null && Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)) {
        Uri uri2 = intent.getData();
       String path = uri2.getPath();
     }
   }
```

Comment: did you override the back button behavior in your app ?

Comment: How do you know the Telegram app doesn't call finish() ?

Comment: yes,i am overriding back in Main activity,i wrote some logic using moveTaskToBack(true) and didn't use super.onBackPressed();, Now i removed moveTaskToBack(true) and placed super.onBackPressed(); it's working fine now.